# charindex function at big query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have below sql query and need to run at bigquery

```
select replace(substring(p.name, charindex(',', p.name), len(p.name)), ',', '') AS [First_Name] from people p
```

so I have tried below big query syntax

```
select replace(SUBSTR(p.name, charindex(',', p.name), len(p.name)), ',', '') AS [First_Name] from people
```

but i am getting below error

```
Function not found: charindex at [1:1]
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

BigQuery has much more powerful string manipulation functions than SQL Server.  A simpler method is:

```
select (split(p.name, ','))[safe_ordinal(1)]
```

You can also use regular expressions:

```
select regexp_extract(p.name, '[^,]*')
```